# Loading an article into a components template in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, article

i would like to load an article into a components templates php code within the Joomla framework.

I can load modules in php, modules in articles, components in articles and and..but i never wanted to load an article into a components php.

Does anybody know of a code snippet for that?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would load the article model in your view like

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$article = $model->getItem((int) $articleId);
```

Now you can access all the fields which are available in the article like `$item->fulltext` or  `$item->introtext`. Have a look at the [article view](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php) to check out all the fancy stuff it does with the article before it displays it.

Comment: Thank you Laoneo. That saves me alot of time.

Comment: So if i want to load the introtext of an article which alias is "000001" how can i achieve that? PHP newbie sorry :)

Comment: I tried this but I could not get it to work. Are there more code needed than this above?

Comment: Do you need to call the app?  `$app        = JFactory::getApplication();` ?

Comment: @DalamHensi it looks as though it should be something like `if ($articleId == "21") {echo $item->fulltext;}` or something like that

Comment: I get the error `404 COM_CONTENT_ERROR_ARTICLE_NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 2):

With Joomla .3.8.10 I got an `Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in .../components/com_content/models/article.php on line 164`

Seems that the params-property is required in model:

```
use Joomla\Registry\Registry; // only for new Registry below
ModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');
$model=JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));
// $params=JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
// An empty registry object is just fine:
$params=new Registry;
$model->setState('params', $params); // params (even empty) is *required* for model
$article=$model->getItem((int) articleId);
```

Not sure if or in what context `ModelLegacy::addIncludePath...` really is required. Does anyone have insight into this?

### Update

You might want to use the Article**s** (note plural) model with an id-filter, as it is able to fetch tags and associations also:

```
use Joomla\Registry\Registry; // for new Registry
$model=JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));
$model->setState('params', new Registry);
$model->setState('filter.article_id', (int) $articleId ); // or use array of ints for multiple articles
$model->setState('load_tags', true); // not available for Article model
$model->setState('show_associations', true);
$articles=$model->getItems();
$article=$articles[0];
```

**Some more filters**

In case you want to fetch articles by other means than id (defaults first). From `components/com_content/models/articles.php`

- filter.article_id: single int or array of ints
- filter.article_id.include: (bool) true|false *`true` to include `false` to exclude given id(s)*
- -> dito for category, author, author_alias
- filter.subcategories: (bool) false|true
- filter.max_category_levels: (int) 1
- filter.date_filtering: (string) off|range|relative
- filter.date_field: (string) created *db table field*²
- filter.start_date_range *for filter.date_filtering==range*
- filter.end_date_range *for filter.date_filtering==range*
- filter.relative_date (int) 0 *number of days in the past from today, for filter.date_filtering==relative*
- filter.tag (int) 0 *tag id*
- load_tags: (bool) true|false
- show_associations: (bool) false|true

**Ordering and limiting**

- list.ordering: (string) ordering *db table field*²
- list.direction: (string) ASC|DESC
- list.limit: (int)
- list.start: (int) 0 *start at zero*

)² Valid fields: 
id, title, alias, checked_out, checked_out_time, catid, category_title, state, access, access_level, created, created_by, ordering, featured, language, hits, publish_up, publish_down, images, urls, filter_tag. All fields checked against whitelist.