# Joomla - get article alias, intro text from database

Tags: php, joomla

I'm writing a module for Joomla which dynamically links to articles, pulling some information from them in the backend. I can get the title and category, but I don't know how to get the article's alias (required for linking, because I would like to use the legible option), and the introtext, because I would like a sample of the article to appear. This is what I have at the moment:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$db->setQuery('SELECT #__content.id as articleID, #__content.title as contentTitle, #__categories.title as catTitle 
               FROM #__content, #__categories 
               WHERE #__content.catid = #__categories.id');
$res = $db->loadObjectList();

for($i = 0; $i < 9 ; $i++){
    echo '<a href="index.php/'.strtolower($res[$res.length - $i - 1]->$catTitle).'/'.$res[$res.length - $i - 1]->articleID.'-'./*alias goes here*/.'">
             <div class="article_'.$i.'">
                <h3>'.$res[$res.length - $i - 1]->contentTitle.'</h3>
                <h5>Posted in '.$res[$res.length - $i - 1]->catTitle.'</h5> 
                <p>'./*introtext goes here*/.'</p>
             </div>
          </a>';
}
```

What can I append to my query to get the intro text and alias?

Comment: First of all, simply looking at the table will tell you the names of the fields.  But second, there is an api for this (JTableContent), you should just use it. Look at any core articles module.

Comment: Or load an article model as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19765783/356375